# Hacer un textfielf javaFX disable pero seleccionble

Tags: java, javafx, jtextfield

Me he creado un textfiel disable en JavaFX, pero al ejecutar y cargar los datos no me deja copiar, ni seleccionar nada, al parecer propiedad disable inhabilita mi caja de texto.

textFiel.setDisable(true);

He intentado cambiar la propiedad editable a true
textFiel.setEditable( true );

Pero ni aún así funciona.

Alguna idea de como puedo solucionar esto o que no estoy haciendo bien?
Gracias !!

Comment: setDisable() se inhabilita la caja para cualquier operación posterior. Deberías clarificar tu pregunta, ¿qué es lo que quieres conseguir exactamente?

Comment: Seleccionar con el mouse parte del texto del textfield y copiarla, ahora no me deja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con setDisable() se inhabilita la caja para cualquier operación posterior.
Para poder seleccionar el contenido y copiarlo, sin dar la posibilidad de editarlo, elimina la línea:

```
textFiel.setDisable( true );
```

y usa:

```
textFiel.setEditable( false );
```

Puedes consultar las Apis de JavaFx, para saber como funcionan los métodos:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/index.html

Comment: Muchas gracias !, lo que he tenido que añadir es un estilo al text-input, cuando sea de sólo lectura cambio el background  ;)